# I cannot get the match function to work with numbers

Tags: google-sheets, match

I can get the match function to work with text, but not with numbers.

I A1 I put "the dog and cat".  In B1 I put "dog".  In C1 I put =match(B1,A1,0) and get #N/a.  So I changed C1 to =match("*"&B1&"*",A1,0) and now it returns 1.  So far so good.

But now I tried a number.  In A1 I put "123456".  In B1 I put "234".  Now I get #N/a and the error says cannot find *234* in match (notice the asterisks).  So I am trying to figure out how to get match to work with numbers.  I must be missing something simple, but I can't figure it out.  Thanks.[spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psPm9.png)

Comment: For wildcards to work with match, convert the numbers to text as such:  `=match("*"&B1&"*",A1&"",0)`

Answer (score 1):

`match()` is for full matches. It already does work with numbers. `match(*value*,*array*,0)` will find the first cell in the input *array* that is a **full** match of *value*

If you want partial match, you can use `find()`.

For example, `find("234","123456")` or `find(234,123456)` both output `2` which is the position of the first occurrence of "234" in "123456". (Both syntax treat input as string.)

---

As for the use of `*`, it appears that `match()` accepts undocumented tokens in its search key if it is a string. So if you insist, `match("*234*","123456",0)` can work, as well as `match("*"&to_text(234)&"*",to_text(123456),0)`.

Answer (score 0):

@rockinfreakshow,
Thanks for the help.  I had to make a couple corrections to make it work in my circumstance.  First, I found it did not work with a date column, so I had to add to_text(A1). Second, I needed it to work with a range, which it would not, so I wrapped it in arrayformula and it now worked, however, I did find as below that the &"" was not necessary once I used to_text:

=arrayformula(match("*"&to_text(B1)&"*",to_text(C1:F1)&"",0)).

@Argyll,
Thanks for the help as well.  I found a similar issue as above with it not working with a range, so same solution and it worked:

=arrayformula(match("*"&to_text(B1)&"*",to_text(C1:F1),0))

Comment: `&""` is used a shortcut to to convert *number* to *text-format* type (in place of *to_text*)

Comment: FYI, if you want a centralized formula to work with a range argument, you should specify it in your original question (and adapt your example as needed). Question-answer pairs should be understandable by themselves to all future readers. Adding requirements after the fact is not a good way to ask questions.